# Why are these Littlewood-Richardson coefficients congruent to 1 mod 8?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, partitions, integer-sequences, algebraic-combinatorics, littlewood-richardson-coefficients

Let $n\in{\mathbb N}$ and write $n=q_1+q_2+\dots+q_t$, where $q_1>q_2>\dots>q_t$ are powers of $2$. Let $\lambda_n$ be the partition with Frobenius symbol $(q_1-1,q_2-1,\dots,q_t-1;q_t,q_{t-1},\dots,q_2,q_1)$. Thus $\lambda_n$ is a partition of $2n$ whose diagonal hooks have lengths $2q_1,2q_2,\dots,2q_t$ and arm lengths $q_1,q_2,\dots,q_t$, respectively. For example $\lambda(15)=(9,6,5,5,2,1,1,1)$.

Next consider the triangular partition $\delta_n:=(n,n-1,\dots,3,2,1)$ and the near triangular partition $\tau_n:=(n,n-1,\dots,3,2)$. Notice that the skew-partition $\tau_{n+1}/\delta_{n-1}$ has staircase shape, with 2 boxes in each of its $n$ rows. Consider the Littlewood-Richardson coefficient $C_n:=C_{\delta_{n-1},\lambda_n}^{\tau_{n+1}}$ (using lrcalc in SageMath):
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11\\
\hline
C_n&1&1&1&1&9&49&89&1&49&1737&16121
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
n&12&13&14&15&16\\
\hline
C_n&281521&10414313&177901001&895807073&1\\
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
n&17&18&19&20&21\\
\hline
C_n&225&37681&1579025&105586569&22888140273
\end{array}
$$

My main question is whether anyone can show or explain why
$$
C_n\equiv1(\hspace{-.3cm}\mod{8}),\quad\mbox{for all $n>0$?}
$$

It is easy to show that $C_n>0$, for all $n$ (fill the first $q_1$ rows of the skew-diagram with the symbols in the first diagonal hook of a row-filling of $\lambda_n$, repeat with the other rows and diagonal hooks). Moreover $C_n=1$, when $n$ is a power of $2$ (as $\lambda_n$ is then a hook partition). Also notice that $C_n=(n-2)^2$, when $n=q+1$, for $q=2,4,8,16$. I do not understand this, but $\lambda_n$ is close to being a hook for these values of $n$.

Another question is to give upper and lower bounds for $C_n$, and show that $C_n$ is unbounded, as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Also show that $C_n$ is monotone increasing between $q+1$ and $2q-1$, for all $q>2$ a power of $2$.

Comment: Sorry, how are these coefficients defined? I am familiar with LR coefficients depending on three diagrams.

Comment: For partitions $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$, $C_{\alpha,\beta}^\gamma$ is the coefficient of the Schur function $s_\gamma$ in $s_\alpha s_\beta$. I'm guessing that your diagram is a Knutson-Tao hive, honeycomb or a Berstein-Zelevinsky triangle.

A more traditional method (used here) is to consider Littlewood-Richardson tableau of shape $\gamma/\alpha$ and weight $\beta$ (or of shape $\gamma/\beta$ and weight $\alpha$). An L-R tableau is semi-standard (non-decreasing on rows, strictly increasing on columns) with a word which is lattice. All these methods are of course equivalent.

Comment: So, you write $C(\gamma/\alpha, \beta)$ for $C_{\alpha, \beta}^\gamma$, right?

Comment: Yes. I guess that hides the commutativity of the coefficients!

Comment: I have listed several models for LR-coefficients here: https://www.symmetricfunctions.com/littlewoodRichardson.htm maybe one of these can help with the conjecture

Comment: Thank you Per. I was not aware of a few of these methods. However it seems unlikely that $C_n$ can be computed explicitly. What I had in mind was showing that a group like $D_8$ acts on the configurations used to compute $C_n$. In arXiv:1204.2484v2 [math.RT], P. B\"urgesser and C. Ikenmeyer defined a connected graph on the "hive flows" which enumerate an L-R coefficient $C_{\alpha,\beta}^\gamma$. This hints at a remarkable structure underlying L-R coefficients.

Comment: also, $\lambda=(9,6,\ldots)$ means that the first column (not row) has length 9, right?

Comment: @Fedor No, I'm listing $\lambda$ by rows. To be clear, its Frobenius symbol is $(7,3,1,0;1,2,4,8)$. So diagonal leg-lengths first, arm-lengths last. Notation from   arXiv:1911.12098 [math.CO]

Comment: Ah, neither arm nor leg of the box A does not contain A itself?

Comment: @Fedor Let $\lambda$ be a partition, with transpose $\lambda^t$. The diagonal hook in the $r$-th row of $\lambda$ has arm length $a=\lambda_r-r$ and leg length $\ell=\lambda^t_r-r$. Thus it contains $a+\ell+1$ boxes; the diagonal box plus the $a$ boxes in row $i$ strictly to the right and the $\ell$ boxes in column $i$ strictly below. I think this is standard terminology.

Comment: I'm used to Andrews's definition of Frobenius symbols, which would give $(8,4,2,1; 7,3,1,0)$ for $(9,6,5,5,2,1,1,1)$, but the connection is clear.